# What is necessary to restart NJ's rebate program for electric vehicles?

Tags: tax-law, new-jersey

NJ has a program which provides a substantial rebate on the purchase or lease of an electric vehicle.

I had [learned that NJ had paused the program](https://chargeup.njcleanenergy.com/) effective November 21st of 2023 due to the relevant funds being depleted and thus unavailable. But the program had been [paused before on April 2023](https://www.nj.gov/bpu/newsroom/2023/approved/20230417.html) and I wasn't even aware that the program at some point restarted.

Can someone advise me on what's necessary for the program to restart? Does it require the passage of legislation by the State Assembly? Or can the governor just authorize the disbursement of already allocated funds? Or does a new calendar year need to start?

I've been unable to identify what triggers the resumption of this program in the State. Can someone help me understand?

Comment: This is more of a political / budget question.

Comment: @MichaelHall I'm assuming the distribution of the rebates is based upon some law; how that law is executed seemed to be within this site's purview, so I figured I'd try here.

Comment: FWIW, when I tried on Money.SE, they thought it was a legal question https://money.stackexchange.com/q/159472/52342

Comment: Fair enough, but you did state "*due to the relevant funds being depleted and thus unavailable*" which would appear to make budget the limiting factor.  Maybe instead of "*what is neccesary to restart*" ask "*what law governs the requirements for distributing funds under the rebate program?*"  (or words to that effect...)  And then read that law.